# How to get the Full text From RSS feeds : Android and IOS

Tags: java, android, ios, rss, rss-reader

How can I get the full text from the **RSS feeds**.

Normally we are getting some basic informations,Is there any option to get full description text from the RSS feeds in **Android** and **iOS**?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tedious way to get more information from the RSS feeds, parse the RSS feed to get the link in the  element , once the link is received you can webscrape the url to fetch more data from it , but then wouldn't recommend it.
 The basic working of RSS is such that you would register with an RSS aggregrator for the information of your choice. RSS aggregrator would then search the registered websites for information and provide you in the form of feeds.